# Micro Price vs multi-level micro price

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, algorithmic-trading, high-frequency, limit-order-book

Why do we use the micro price $$p_m = \frac{B_{\text{size}} A_{\text{price}} + A_{\text{size}} B_{\text{price}}}{ A_{\text{size}} + B_{\text{size}}}$$ rather than fixing $A_{\text{size}}$ and $B_{\text{size}}$ to some constant and weighting the $A_{\text{price}}$ and  $B_{\text{price}}$ to this value? Does the micro price not suffer if someone places a new low ask/high bid, but in small size?

Comment: The answer is yes the microprice has obvious flaws such as the one you mentioned with a very imbalanced top of book. The key point is that what one considers to be the fair price of a security depends on the use case of the price e.g. often you may be more interested in a pair of prices - the price at which you will be able to execute a buy order at a certain size, and the price at which you can execute a sell order at that size. Your best estimate of the value of the asset may not be exactly in the middle of these two values, either, depending on the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you fix $A_{\text{size}}$ and $B_{\text{size}}$ to a constant, you would lose the information about the liquidity available at the best bid and ask levels. This could lead to an inaccurate representation of the market's sentiment, as larger or smaller orders at the best bid and ask prices might have a significant impact on price movements.

The micro price may indeed suffer if someone places a new low ask or high bid but in a small size, as it would affect the weighted average calculation. However, this issue is mitigated to some extent by considering the order sizes in the calculation. Large orders will have a greater influence on the micro price, while small orders will have a lesser impact. Additionally, the micro price is continuously updated as the order book changes, so the influence of small, potentially anomalous orders will likely be temporary.

Comment: Is there any good way to consider a multi-level approach? Ex. rather than fixing $A_\text{size}$ to some constant, consider not only the best ask, but rather the $n$ best asks and weight the ask prices (according to volume or otherwise)?

Comment: Yes, that approach would be called VWAP (Volume-weighted average price).

Comment: Is that not longer time scale than the micro-price (ie. closer to a moving average of sorts rather than an instantaneous measure)?

Comment: You are correct, that was imprecise of me. The instantaneous estimate is called volume-weighted mid-price or depth-weighted mid-price.

Comment: How is this value calculated? I can't seem to find anything about either terms online

Comment: A calculation and more on how to analyze the order book you can find in here: https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=565324. It seems like there is no common terminology for what I would consider to be the volume-weighted mid-price.